# showed or shown

Tags: grammar

I need some help with this because it is quite confusing for me please:

Previous research has shown

or

Previous research has showed

which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

There are two past participles for "to show"; they are "shown" the usual one, and "showed"; however "showed" is rarely used ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/show_1?q=show).

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=15&smoothing=3&content=has+showed%2Chas+shown&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20showed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20shown%3B%2Cc0) shows how rare is "showed".
It is so rare that some sources do not list that form ([the irreguar verbs](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/)).

Comment: So I should use:

Comment: So I should use: Past research has shown?

Comment: @SayedAli That's what I would do; however I wouldn't correct your choice for the time being if you were to use "showed"; I would tell you that there is no obvious reason for chosing "showed".

Comment: many thanks - that is very helpful